# UITableViewDataSource Method -cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

If I have my data in an NSArray, and I can NSLog that data in my -cellForRowAtIndexPath method, would there be any reason why I wouldn't be able see the data in my UITableView using code like:

```
static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *simpleCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
        if (simpleCell == nil) {
            simpleCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
        }
        NSUInteger row;
        row = [indexPath row];
        simpleCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        simpleCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            simpleCell.textLabel.text = [_categoriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
return simpleCell;
```

I'm wondering if I missed a "gotcha" or something.  I have this data verbatim in one popover and it works fine.  But then when I put it in another popover, it shows nothing.  So I'm stumped!  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you changing the background color of the table view?

Comment: Yeah, the background color of the tableview is set in my popover to be clearColor.  If there was data, the tableView should scroll right?  Like if I messed up and the text and tableView colors were the same.  The table does not scroll, so I assume that there is no data in there even though I can NSLog my array.

Comment: Does the other popover set the `dataSource` and `delegate` to the same place the popover that works does?  Since you aren't seeing anything at all, I'm tempted to say it just doesn't know where to call its data from, and that is an easy thing to miss

Comment: have u tried to print [_categoriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
is this simpleCell.textLabel.text = [_categoriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
doing its part successfully?

Comment: @slev, yes I just replaced the contentViewController with this one.

Comment: @Anshikha, yes I NSLog that and it has the data.  But you are right, something in there is getting messed up b/c it's obviously not displaying my data.

Comment: @crystal: hey! it's funny but... what is the color of the cell there...it might be possible that text and cell both have white color and that may be the reason that you can't see the text there....it might be a possible reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for trying to help me troubleshoot this problem.  It was not a color issue.  I finally got it to work, but I'm not quite sure why.  Maybe someone else can chime in as why it works now. So in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method and other datasource methods, I have code like

```
if (tableView == tableView1 || tableView == _categoriesTableView || tableView == tableView2) {
...
if (tableView == tableView1) {
//do stuff
}
else if (tableView == _categoriesTableView) {
// do real stuff
}
else {
// do stuff
}
```

When I first had it working, I had a popover from a button that would show tableView1, then you would select a row in that table, to present another popover like _categoriesTableView.  So this code worked fine.  However, when I would try to change the first popover to show the _categoriesTableView, leaving all other code the same, no data would show correctly.  Then instead of replacing the tableView1 initializing data for the popover, I still initialized it, but just did not present it in the popover, and now everything works.  Not sure why the uninitialized memory of tableView1 would cause the problem since when I followed the code with breakpoints, my "do real stuff" was run, just wouldn't do what it was supposed to (display the data in the UITableView).

Answer (score 0):

How many rows and sections do you have defined for your table? If they are not defined correctly you won't have any data populating. I'm also assuming that your tableViewCell is not white, since you are setting the color of the text to white.

Comment: Yeah the tableview is set to clearColor (I set it when I present it in the popover).  I don't think there is tableView data as the tableView won't scroll.  For the rows, I return the [_categoriesArray count], for the section for all my tableViews, I return 1.

Comment: Have you confirmed the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is being run when your tableView should load?

Comment: Yes. I can see it with breakpoints and if I NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing your cell like this:

```
simpleCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
```

By default this creates a cell with an opaque white background.  Then you're setting your text color to white:

```
simpleCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Try setting a different background color for your cell:

```
simpleCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

If you really need the table to be transparent you could set the color for both the cell and the tableView itself to `[UIColor clearColor]`, but be aware that transparency really hurts your scrolling frame rate.  You're better off using opaque views wherever possible.